# HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode emulator: warning: opening audio input failed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-emulator

Ques:emulator: HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode emulator: warning: opening audio input failed emulator window was out of view and was recentered.

This is my first android project but i had to face the same error many times.I just want to run my application successfully but this error keeps popping out. I am using win 7 operating system ,4 gb ram, allocated 1 gb for emulator and i am using nexus 5 as virtual emulator.Can anybody please help me with this issue?

Comment: reduced virtual emulator ram(nexus 5) to 512mb

Comment: Wow i asked a question where no professional  is able to answer it  :D